# Creating an array in one function and then using it somewhere else

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TL:DR, I am creating a randomly-ordered array in one React component, that I need to use in another component - but the second component keeps re-rendering and therefore re-shuffling my array - but I need its order to be fixed once it gets imported for the first time.

First things first - if I am doing this in a needlessly roundabout way, please do say so, I'm not set on this way.

I am making a flashcard program, and I want to give users the option to play games with random selections of their cards.

The way I am currently trying to do this, is that I have a functional component (because I need to do things like dispatch in it) which works as follows - I've added comments to explain what each bit does:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getPosts } from "../../actions/posts";


export function WORDS() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [localUser, setLocalUser] = useState();


  //get all users
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, []);

  const users = useSelector((state) => state.posts);


  
  //set user to match the user in the local storage
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")));
  }, [localStorage]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(users.filter((user) => user.code == localUser?.code)[0]);
  }, [users, localUser]);



  //create an array of 8 random words from the users cards object
  let RandomArray = []
  if (user) {
    for (let i = 0; RandomArray.length < 8; i++) {
      let RanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * user.cards.length);
      !RandomArray.includes(user.cards[RanNum]) && RandomArray.push(user.cards[RanNum])
    }
  }




  //create duplicates of each word and make an array of them all, once with the front of the card in first place and once with the back in first place
  let shuffledWords = [];

RandomArray.map((word) => {
  let newWord = { Q: word.front, A: word.back };
  let newWord2 = { Q: word.back, A: word.front };
  shuffledWords.push(newWord);
  shuffledWords.push(newWord2);
});



//shuffle that array
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}

  shuffleArray(shuffledWords);



  //return this array so I can call it in other functions
  return { shuffledWords }
};
```

The game is then a kind of 'memory' game, where users try and match words with their translation. That's currently running like this, again with comments (please excuse the excessive inline styling - I will move that all to the stylesheet eventually but I've left it in here just in case any of that is what's causing the problems.):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { WORDS as ImportedWords } from "./WORDS";

export const Memory = () => {

  //import words from function
  const ImportedArray = ImportedWords().shuffledWords

  //create state variables for the first and second card a user pics
  const [selectL1, setSelectL1] = useState("");
  const [selectL2, setSelectL2] = useState("");

  //create state variables for whether to display a card or not and whether or not it was correct
  const [show, setShow] = useState([]);
  const [correct, setCorrect] = useState([]);

  //variable to make cards unclickable while they're spinning over
  const [clickable, setClickable] = useState(true);


  //if user has picked two cards, check if they match and either set them to correct or turn them back over
  if (selectL1 && selectL2) {
    clickable == true && setClickable(false);

    let selectQ = ImportedArray.filter((word) => word.Q == selectL1)[0];

    console.log("selectQ: ", selectQ);

    selectQ && selectL2 == selectQ.A
      ? correct.push(selectL1, selectL2)
      : console.log("Incorrect!");

    setTimeout(function () {
      setSelectL1("");
      setSelectL2("");
      setShow([]);
      setClickable(true);
      //correct.length == shuffledWords.length * 2 && alert("You win!");
    }, 800);
  }


  //show the card a user's clicked
  const selectCard = (wordId) => {
    !selectL1 ? setSelectL1(wordId) : setSelectL2(wordId);

    show.push(wordId);
  };


  
  return (
    <div className="memory-game-wrapper">
      <div
        style={{ perspective: "2000px", pointerEvents: !clickable && "none" }}
      >

      {/* filter through the imported array and display them */}
        {ImportedArray.map((word) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={
                show.includes(word.Q) || correct.includes(word.Q)
                  ? "card flip"
                  : "card"
              }
              id={word.Q}
              style={{
                borderRadius: "5px",
                display: "inline-block",
                width: "100px",
                height: "180px",
                backgroundColor: "rgb(185, 204, 218)",
                margin: "5px",
              }}
              onClick={() =>
                !correct.includes(word.Q) &&
                !show.includes(word.Q) &&
                selectCard(word.Q)
              }
            >
              <div
                className="back-face"
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  height: "100%",
                  width: "100%",
                  display: "flex",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <center>
                  <span style={{ userSelect: "none" }}></span>
                </center>
              </div>

              <div
                className="front-face"
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  height: "100%",
                  display: "flex",
                  width: "100%",
                  borderRadius: "5px",
                  border: "5px solid rgb(185, 204, 218)",
                  boxSizing: "border-box",
                  backgroundColor: correct.includes(word.Q)
                    ? "white"
                    : "rgb(185, 204, 218)",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <h3 style={{ userSelect: "none" }}>{word.Q}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I suspected that what was happening was that the whole array is being re-rendered any time a user clicks on any of the cards, which means the order gets shuffled again - and makes the game unplayable, so I whacked in a `console.log(ImportedArray[0])` to check and yes, that is definitely happening. But I can't work out how to stop it?

Any ideas??

Comment: I have a working version of the game with dummy data, which you can see here, to see how it's meant to work: https://flashbackflashcards.netlify.app/games/memory

Comment: And here's my GitHub: https://github.com/gordonmaloney/Flashback
The relevant files are in client/src/components/Games

Comment: just a random idea: save your shuffled cards in more persistent state ( like local storage ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Memory component is not conditionally mounted/unmounted in the parent, like `{condition && <Memory}`, you can use the useMemo hook to memoize the imported words at the first render.

```js
const ImportedArray = useMemo(() => ImportedWords().shuffledWords, []);
```

Anyway the `WORDS` component is a candidate to be a custom hook where you can encapsulate the words logic. it should be named `useWords`

Comment: Thanks Antonio! Had to give give useMemo a dependency array because it took a moment to return the useWords hook, but the below does exactly what I was after:
```
  const ImportedWords = useWords();
  const ImportedArray = useMemo(() => ImportedWords.shuffledWords, [ImportedWords.shuffledWords.length]);
```

I had also never used useMemo before, and useWords was the first time I'd ever made my own hook - so not only did you solve my problem for me, but you taught me a new hook, AND how to make my own hooks! 

Comment: @GordonMaloney glad it helped you.